# Modeling null transitions in the Hidden Markov Model for use with the Viterbi algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, markov-process, pattern-recognition

I've implemented the classic HMM model from [Rabiner's tutorial](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/rabiner.pdf) for gesture recognition and it has worked well. Now, I'm trying to implement the [HMM Threshold Model](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=799904) which calls for an HMM with **null transitions**.

Null transitions do not provide any output symbols and the threshold model has 2 states which are connected to all the others through null transitions. How do I model this so that I can still use the Viterbi algorithm to evaluate the likelihood of an observed sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "Statistical methods for speech recognition", Jelinek gives a method of merging null transitions to create a new HMM that emits after every transition.

Alternatively, you might be able to run the Viterbi algorithm on a 3-dimensional lattice (rather than the standard (hidden states) X (emitted symbols) 2d lattice). The best example of this is probably for the Profile HMM ("Profile hidden Markov models." S.R. Eddy).